# unable to auto-start animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

i used following code to auto-play `mp3` from stream link,

```
  document.getElementById('myAudio').play();
```

is there a way to trigger animation auto start, in below code animation starts only on mouse click, can some one help to auto start animation

**and this works in localhost but here in code snippet audio play doestn works**

```js
var player = $('.player'),
    audio = player.find('audio'),
    duration = $('.duration'),
    currentTime = $('.current-time'),
    progressBar = $('.progress span'),
    mouseDown = false,
    rewind, showCurrentTime;

function secsToMins(time) {
  var int = Math.floor(time),
      mins = Math.floor(int / 60),
      secs = int % 60,
      newTime = mins + ':' + ('0' + secs).slice(-2);
  
  return newTime;
}

function getCurrentTime() {
  var currentTimeFormatted = secsToMins(audio[0].currentTime),
      currentTimePercentage = audio[0].currentTime / audio[0].duration * 100;
  
  currentTime.text(currentTimeFormatted);
  progressBar.css('width', currentTimePercentage + '%');
  
  if (player.hasClass('playing')) {
    showCurrentTime = requestAnimationFrame(getCurrentTime);
  } else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(showCurrentTime);
  }
}

audio.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  var durationFormatted = secsToMins(audio[0].duration);
  duration.text(durationFormatted);
}).on('ended', function() {
  if ($('.repeat').hasClass('active')) {
    audio[0].currentTime = 0;
    audio[0].play();
  } else {
    player.removeClass('playing').addClass('paused');
    audio[0].currentTime = 0;
  }
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  
  if (self.hasClass('play-pause') && player.hasClass('paused')) {
    player.removeClass('paused').addClass('playing');
    audio[0].play();
    getCurrentTime();
  } else if (self.hasClass('play-pause') && player.hasClass('playing')) {
    player.removeClass('playing').addClass('paused');
    audio[0].pause();
  }
  
  if (self.hasClass('shuffle') || self.hasClass('repeat')) {
    self.toggleClass('active');
  }
}).on('mousedown', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  
  if (self.hasClass('ff')) {
    player.addClass('ffing');
    audio[0].playbackRate = 2;
  }
  
  if (self.hasClass('rw')) {
    player.addClass('rwing');
    rewind = setInterval(function() { audio[0].currentTime -= .3; }, 100);
  }
}).on('mouseup', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  
  if (self.hasClass('ff')) {
    player.removeClass('ffing');
    audio[0].playbackRate = 1;
  }
  
  if (self.hasClass('rw')) {
    player.removeClass('rwing');
    clearInterval(rewind);
  }
});

player.on('mousedown mouseup', function() {
  mouseDown = !mouseDown;
});

progressBar.parent().on('click mousemove', function(e) {
  var self = $(this),
      totalWidth = self.width(),
      offsetX = e.offsetX,
      offsetPercentage = offsetX / totalWidth;
  
  if (mouseDown || e.type === 'click') {
    audio[0].currentTime = audio[0].duration * offsetPercentage;
    if (player.hasClass('paused')) {
      progressBar.css('width', offsetPercentage * 100 + '%');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: inherit; }

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  background-color: #222;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2 { font-size: 87.5%; }

.player {
  position: relative;
  width: 20em;
  min-height: 20em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  box-shadow:
    0 1.5em 2em -1em rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
    inset 0 0.0625em 0 rgba(255,255,255,1),
    inset 0 -0.125em 0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.album {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  margin-bottom: -13%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%,-25%);
  background-color: #111;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow:
    0 0.0625em 0.1875em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    0 0 0.125em 0.3125em #ddd,
    0 0.0625em 0 0.375em #bbb,
    0 0 0.375em 0.325em rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
    0 0 0.5em 0.375em rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
    0 0.25em 1em 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    inset 0 0 0 0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.1875em rgba(255,255,255,1),
    inset 0 0 0 0.375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.4375em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.5625em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 0.625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.6875em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 0.75em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.8125em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 0.875em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.9375em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.0625em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 1.125em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.1875em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 1.25em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.3125em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 1.375em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 1.4375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.5em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 1.5625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.625em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 1.6875em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.75em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 1.8125em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.875em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 1.9375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 2.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.125em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.1875em rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
    inset 0 0 0 2.25em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.3125em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 2.375em rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
    inset 0 0 0 2.4375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.5em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 2.5625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.625em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 2.6875em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.75em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 2.8125em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.875em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 2.9375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 3em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 3.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 3.125em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 3.1875em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 3.25em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 3.3125em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 3.375em rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
    inset 0 0 0 3.4375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 3.5em rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.album::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      -45deg,
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 30%,
      rgba(255,255,255,0.125),
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      -48deg,
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 45%,
      rgba(255,255,255,0.075),
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 55%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      -42deg,
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 45%,
      rgba(255,255,255,0.075),
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 55%
    ),
    radial-gradient(
      circle at top left,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%
    ),
    radial-gradient(
      circle at bottom right,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%
    );
}

.cover,
.cover div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(0) translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite paused;
}

.ffing .cover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.cover div {
  border-radius: 0;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite reverse paused;
}

.rwing .cover div {
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite reverse running;
}

.cover::before,
.cover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(0) translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.0625em rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite reverse paused;
}

.cover::after {
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 0.3125em;
  margin-top: -0.0625em;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0.125em;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 -0.0625em 0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0.0625em -0.0625em 0.125em rgba(255,255,255,0.15),
    inset -0.0625em -0.0625em 0.125em rgba(255,255,255,0.15),
    inset 0 -0.125em 0.125em rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
    0 0.0625em 0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    0 0.0625em 0.25em 0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    0 0 0.25em 0.125em rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.ffing .cover::before,
.ffing .cover::after {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.cover img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(0) translate(-50%,-50%);
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite paused;
}

.paused .cover img {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.playing .cover img {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.info {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0.0625em rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.time {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.time > * {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.progress {
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 0.125em;
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 0.0625em;
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625em rgba(255,255,255,1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress span {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #666;
}

.actions {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 0 1.125em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ddd, #f6f6f6);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 0.125em solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.25em 1em -0.25em rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

.button:hover::before {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.play-pause {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
}

.rw {
  right: -0.25em;
  margin-left: 0.375em;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.ff {
  left: -0.25em;
  margin-right: 0.375em;
}

.button .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.button .arrow::before,
.button .arrow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.2,0.7) rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 0.125em 0.125em -0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    0.0625em 0.0625em 0.125em rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.button .arrow::after {
  left: 0;
  transform: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0.0625em 0 0.125em -0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.paused .play-pause .arrow {
  margin-left: 0.1875em;
}

.playing .play-pause .arrow::before,
.playing .play-pause .arrow::after {
  left: 0;
  width: 0.4375em;
  transform: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0.0625em 0.125em 0.125em -0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    0.0625em 0.0625em 0.125em rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.playing .play-pause .arrow::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

.rw .arrow,
.ff .arrow {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.rw .arrow:first-child,
.ff .arrow:first-child {
  margin-left: -4%;
}

.button:active .arrow::before,
.playing .play-pause .arrow::before,
.playing .play-pause .arrow::after {
  background-color: #cef;
}

.shuffle {
  width: 1.375em;
  height: 1.375em;
  color: #d5d5d5;
}

.shuffle .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875em;
  left: 0;
  width: 0.375em;
  height: 0.125em;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

.shuffle .arrow::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% + 0.125em);
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 1em;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
  border-bottom: 0.125em solid;
  border-left: 0.125em solid;
  box-shadow:
    -0.3125em 0em 0 -0.1875em #eee,
    inset 0.375em 0.25em 0 -0.25em #eee;
}

.shuffle .arrow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.6875em;
  left: calc(100% + 0.625em);
  border: 0.25em solid transparent;
  border-left-width: 0.375em;
  border-left-color: currentColor;
}

.shuffle .arrow:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0 0.5em;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.repeat {
  width: 1.375em;
  height: 1.375em;
  color: #d5d5d5;
  border: 0.125em solid;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.repeat::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.125em;
  left: -0.125em;
  width: calc(100% + 0.25em);
  height: calc(100% + 0.25em);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border: 0.125em solid transparent;
  border-right-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.repeat::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -0.3125em;
  border: 0.25em solid transparent;
  border-top-width: 0.375em;
  border-top-color: currentColor;
}

.shuffle.active,
.repeat.active {
  color: #bde;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%,-50%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="player paused">
            <div class="album">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/38273/3rdburglar-cover-192.jpg" alt="3rdburglar by Wordburglar" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <div class="time">
                    <span class="current-time">0:00</span>
                    <span class="progress"><span></span></span>
                    <span class="duration">0:00</span>
                </div>

                <h1>Drawings With Words</h1>
                <h2>3RDBURGLAR</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="actions">
                <button class="shuffle">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                </button>
                <button class="button rw">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                </button>
                <button class="button play-pause">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                </button>
                <button class="button ff">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                </button>
                <button class="repeat"></button>
            </div>

            <audio id="myAudio">
                <source src="http://163.172.165.94:8728/;stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
            </audio>
            <script>
                document.getElementById('myAudio').play();
            </script>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `playing class` in the `div` with `class  album`

```js
var player = $('.player'),
    audio = player.find('audio'),
    
    duration = $('.duration'),
    currentTime = $('.current-time'),
    progressBar = $('.progress span'),
    mouseDown = false,
    rewind, showCurrentTime;
    audio[0].play()

function secsToMins(time) {
  var int = Math.floor(time),
      mins = Math.floor(int / 60),
      secs = int % 60,
      newTime = mins + ':' + ('0' + secs).slice(-2);
  
  return newTime;
}

function getCurrentTime() {
  var currentTimeFormatted = secsToMins(audio[0].currentTime),
      currentTimePercentage = audio[0].currentTime / audio[0].duration * 100;
  
  currentTime.text(currentTimeFormatted);
  progressBar.css('width', currentTimePercentage + '%');
  
  if (player.hasClass('playing')) {
    showCurrentTime = requestAnimationFrame(getCurrentTime);
  } else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(showCurrentTime);
  }
}

audio.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  var durationFormatted = secsToMins(audio[0].duration);
  duration.text(durationFormatted);
}).on('ended', function() {
  if ($('.repeat').hasClass('active')) {
    audio[0].currentTime = 0;
    audio[0].play();
  } else {
    player.removeClass('playing').addClass('paused');
    audio[0].currentTime = 0;
  }
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  
  if (self.hasClass('play-pause') && player.hasClass('paused')) {
    player.removeClass('paused').addClass('playing');
    audio[0].play();
    getCurrentTime();
  } else if (self.hasClass('play-pause') && player.hasClass('playing')) {
    player.removeClass('playing').addClass('paused');
    audio[0].pause();
  }
  
  if (self.hasClass('shuffle') || self.hasClass('repeat')) {
    self.toggleClass('active');
  }
}).on('mousedown', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  
  if (self.hasClass('ff')) {
    player.addClass('ffing');
    audio[0].playbackRate = 2;
  }
  
  if (self.hasClass('rw')) {
    player.addClass('rwing');
    rewind = setInterval(function() { audio[0].currentTime -= .3; }, 100);
  }
}).on('mouseup', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  
  if (self.hasClass('ff')) {
    player.removeClass('ffing');
    audio[0].playbackRate = 1;
  }
  
  if (self.hasClass('rw')) {
    player.removeClass('rwing');
    clearInterval(rewind);
  }
});

player.on('mousedown mouseup', function() {
  mouseDown = !mouseDown;
});

progressBar.parent().on('click mousemove', function(e) {
  var self = $(this),
      totalWidth = self.width(),
      offsetX = e.offsetX,
      offsetPercentage = offsetX / totalWidth;
  
  if (mouseDown || e.type === 'click') {
    audio[0].currentTime = audio[0].duration * offsetPercentage;
    if (player.hasClass('paused')) {
      progressBar.css('width', offsetPercentage * 100 + '%');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: inherit; }

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  background-color: #222;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2 { font-size: 87.5%; }

.player {
  position: relative;
  width: 20em;
  min-height: 20em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  box-shadow:
    0 1.5em 2em -1em rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
    inset 0 0.0625em 0 rgba(255,255,255,1),
    inset 0 -0.125em 0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.album {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  margin-bottom: -13%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%,-25%);
  background-color: #111;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow:
    0 0.0625em 0.1875em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    0 0 0.125em 0.3125em #ddd,
    0 0.0625em 0 0.375em #bbb,
    0 0 0.375em 0.325em rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
    0 0 0.5em 0.375em rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
    0 0.25em 1em 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    inset 0 0 0 0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.1875em rgba(255,255,255,1),
    inset 0 0 0 0.375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.4375em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.5625em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 0.625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.6875em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 0.75em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.8125em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 0.875em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 0.9375em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.0625em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 1.125em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.1875em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 1.25em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.3125em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 1.375em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 1.4375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.5em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 1.5625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.625em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 1.6875em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.75em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 1.8125em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 1.875em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 1.9375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 2.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.125em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.1875em rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
    inset 0 0 0 2.25em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.3125em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 2.375em rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
    inset 0 0 0 2.4375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.5em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 2.5625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.625em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 2.6875em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.75em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 2.8125em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 2.875em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 2.9375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 3em rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 0 0 3.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 3.125em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 3.1875em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 3.25em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 3.3125em rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
    inset 0 0 0 3.375em rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
    inset 0 0 0 3.4375em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0 0 0 3.5em rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.album::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      -45deg,
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 30%,
      rgba(255,255,255,0.125),
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      -48deg,
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 45%,
      rgba(255,255,255,0.075),
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 55%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      -42deg,
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 45%,
      rgba(255,255,255,0.075),
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 55%
    ),
    radial-gradient(
      circle at top left,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%
    ),
    radial-gradient(
      circle at bottom right,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%
    );
}

.cover,
.cover div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite paused;
}

.ffing .cover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.cover div {
  border-radius: 0;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite reverse paused;
}

.rwing .cover div {
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite reverse running;
}

.cover::before,
.cover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(0) translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.0625em rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite reverse paused;
}

.cover::after {
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 0.3125em;
  margin-top: -0.0625em;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0.125em;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 -0.0625em 0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    inset 0.0625em -0.0625em 0.125em rgba(255,255,255,0.15),
    inset -0.0625em -0.0625em 0.125em rgba(255,255,255,0.15),
    inset 0 -0.125em 0.125em rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
    0 0.0625em 0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    0 0.0625em 0.25em 0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    0 0 0.25em 0.125em rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.ffing .cover::before,
.ffing .cover::after {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.cover img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(0) translate(-50%,-50%);
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite paused;
}

.paused .cover img {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.playing .cover img {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.info {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0.0625em rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.time {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.time > * {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.progress {
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 0.125em;
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 0.0625em;
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625em rgba(255,255,255,1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress span {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #666;
}

.actions {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 0 1.125em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ddd, #f6f6f6);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 0.125em solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.25em 1em -0.25em rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

.button:hover::before {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.play-pause {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
}

.rw {
  right: -0.25em;
  margin-left: 0.375em;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.ff {
  left: -0.25em;
  margin-right: 0.375em;
}

.button .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.button .arrow::before,
.button .arrow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.2,0.7) rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 0.125em 0.125em -0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    0.0625em 0.0625em 0.125em rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.button .arrow::after {
  left: 0;
  transform: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0.0625em 0 0.125em -0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.paused .play-pause .arrow {
  margin-left: 0.1875em;
}

.playing .play-pause .arrow::before,
.playing .play-pause .arrow::after {
  left: 0;
  width: 0.4375em;
  transform: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0.0625em 0.125em 0.125em -0.0625em rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    0.0625em 0.0625em 0.125em rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.playing .play-pause .arrow::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

.rw .arrow,
.ff .arrow {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.rw .arrow:first-child,
.ff .arrow:first-child {
  margin-left: -4%;
}

.button:active .arrow::before,
.playing .play-pause .arrow::before,
.playing .play-pause .arrow::after {
  background-color: #cef;
}

.shuffle {
  width: 1.375em;
  height: 1.375em;
  color: #d5d5d5;
}

.shuffle .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875em;
  left: 0;
  width: 0.375em;
  height: 0.125em;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

.shuffle .arrow::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% + 0.125em);
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 1em;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
  border-bottom: 0.125em solid;
  border-left: 0.125em solid;
  box-shadow:
    -0.3125em 0em 0 -0.1875em #eee,
    inset 0.375em 0.25em 0 -0.25em #eee;
}

.shuffle .arrow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.6875em;
  left: calc(100% + 0.625em);
  border: 0.25em solid transparent;
  border-left-width: 0.375em;
  border-left-color: currentColor;
}

.shuffle .arrow:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0 0.5em;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.repeat {
  width: 1.375em;
  height: 1.375em;
  color: #d5d5d5;
  border: 0.125em solid;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.repeat::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.125em;
  left: -0.125em;
  width: calc(100% + 0.25em);
  height: calc(100% + 0.25em);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border: 0.125em solid transparent;
  border-right-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.repeat::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -0.3125em;
  border: 0.25em solid transparent;
  border-top-width: 0.375em;
  border-top-color: currentColor;
}

.shuffle.active,
.repeat.active {
  color: #bde;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-50%,-50%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="player paused">
            <div class="album playing" >
                <div class="cover ">
                    <div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/38273/3rdburglar-cover-192.jpg" alt="3rdburglar by Wordburglar" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <div class="time">
                    <span class="current-time">0:00</span>
                    <span class="progress"><span></span></span>
                    <span class="duration">0:00</span>
                </div>

                <h1>Drawings With Words</h1>
                <h2>3RDBURGLAR</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="actions">
                <button class="shuffle">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                </button>
                <button class="button rw">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                </button>
                <button class="button play-pause">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                </button>
                <button class="button ff">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                </button>
                <button class="repeat"></button>
            </div>

            <audio id="myAudio">
                <source src="http://163.172.165.94:8728/;stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
            </audio>
            <script>
                document.getElementById('myAudio').play();
            </script>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is playing on load. can you be more specific, i think im getting you wrong

Comment: the audio source which i have placed  `<source src="http://163.172.165.94:8728/;stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3">` does'nt auto-play on my local host

Comment: check now once more

Answer (score 1):

for autoplay

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById('myAudio').play();
  });
 </script>
```

for animation

```
<div class="album playing" >
    <div class="cover ">
       <div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/38273/3rdburglar-cover-192.jpg" alt="3rdburglar by Wordburglar" /></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: how to auto animate, please check my example

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (event) { 
        $('#myAudio').play(); 
    });
</script>
```

Instead of

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('myAudio').play();
</script>
```

You trigger the animation simulating the user's click:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (event) { 
        $('.button.play-pause').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how to auto animate, please check my example

Comment: Done, now it also triggers the animation (and everything else a user's click would)